# How to access GTimer provided by GLib in Perl?

Tags: perl, gtk, glib

I'm writing an application using Perl and Gtk2-Perl that keeps track of elapsed time. It needs to perform a certain function when a count down timer expires. It would be nice if the timer generated a signal when it expired.

I see that GLib provides a GTimer structure for this purpose, but I can't find any documentation about how to access this through Gtk2-Perl, or if this is even advisable, because maybe there's a better solution that's native to Perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Glib::Timeout->add`](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Glib/MainLoop.html#integer_Glib_Timeout) or [`Glib::Timeout->add_seconds`](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Glib/MainLoop.html#integer_Glib_Timeout1). 
Note that [`add_seconds` does more than just multiply the interval by 1000](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeGoals/UseTimeoutAddSeconds).

GLib's [GTimer](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Timers.html) just keeps track of elapsed time; it doesn't emit signals.  The Perlish equivalent of a GTimer would be [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time%3a%3aHiRes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can make a call to the Alarm function. That should do the trick